# Connection failed between Neo4j Community Server and Gephi

Tags: neo4j, gephi, neo4j-apoc

I've created a graph in the Neo4j Community Edition server. When it was smaller I could visualize it with Chrome on http://localhost:7474/ by executing a simple MATCH (n) RETURN (n) query. As the graph got larger, the Chrome visual became far too slow.

So I attempted to establish a streaming connection between the Neo4j server (V3.5.11) and Gephi (V0.9.2). I read a number of other Stack Overflow questions and answers about this issue, but none of them seemed to bump into the same errors.

I installed the Gephi plugin, then clicked the green plus sign to add a streaming connection. I entered http://localhost:8080/workspace1?operation=updateGraph as the URL, selected JSON as the stream type, and entered the corresponding basic authentication information. The app returned with the following message

```
WARNING: Unable to connect to stream http://localhost:8080.workspace1?operation=updateGraph
java.net.ConnectionException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

I selected the "Master Server" in the list of streaming connections, right-clicked and selected Start. The red button to the left of the label turned green, perhaps a positive development. Then I went to Chrome, which was already connected to the Neo4j server, and issued the following query suggested by another StackOverflow question-answer.

```
match path = (n)--()
with collect(path) as paths
call apoc.gephi.add(null, 'workspace1', paths, '') yield nodes, relationships, time
return nodes, relationships, time
```

The Neo4j server returned the following message.

```
ERROR
**Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed:**
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.gephi.add`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't read url or key http://localhost:8080/workspace1?operation=updateGraph as json: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode
```

What am I doing wrong?